# How do I add my order by field to this select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

To avoid "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.", I need to add AssessmentSuperSet.Deadline to my SELECT statement at the top.  Where should I do this?  Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF(
    (SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(AssessmentSuperSet.Title) 
            from AssessmentSuperSet inner join AssessmentSet on AssessmentSuperSet.SuperSetID =     AssessmentSet.SuperSetID
            where ClassID = '8KF/En 14/15' order by AssessmentSuperSet.Deadline ASC
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT StudentID, FName, SName, ' + @cols + ' from 
     (
        select KS3Assessments.StudentID,
          Pupils.FName,
          Pupils.SName,
          KS3Assessments.NCLevel,
          AssessmentSuperSet.Title
        from KS3Assessments inner join Pupils on KS3Assessments.StudentID = Pupils.StudentID
                            inner join AssessmentSuperSet on KS3Assessments.SuperSetID = AssessmentSuperSet.SuperSetID                              
        where Pupils.GroupDesignation = ''8KF/En 14/15''
    ) x
    pivot (max(NCLevel) for Title in (' + @cols + ') ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: The use of DISTINCT is Often an indicator your design is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of distinct try using a group by clause:

```
select @cols = STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(AssessmentSuperSet.Title) 
            from AssessmentSuperSet inner join AssessmentSet on AssessmentSuperSet.SuperSetID =     AssessmentSet.SuperSetID
            where ClassID = '8KF/En 14/15' 
          group by AssessmentSuperSet.title, AssessmentSuperSet.Deadline
          order by AssessmentSuperSet.Deadline ASC
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT StudentID, FName, SName, ' + @cols + ' from 
     (
        select KS3Assessments.StudentID,
          Pupils.FName,
          Pupils.SName,
          KS3Assessments.NCLevel,
          AssessmentSuperSet.Title
        from KS3Assessments inner join Pupils on KS3Assessments.StudentID = Pupils.StudentID
                            inner join AssessmentSuperSet on KS3Assessments.SuperSetID = AssessmentSuperSet.SuperSetID                              
        where Pupils.GroupDesignation = ''8KF/En 14/15''
    ) x
    pivot (max(NCLevel) for Title in (' + @cols + ') ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Since you didn't provide any suitable test data I haven't tried it.